# Application configuration file in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, configuration, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin form app.

I would like to have a config file that includes all application configuration constants such as default colors, fonts family name, general URLs etc..

What is the best practice to do that?

Comment: You can create a static class and have all the items as constant or readonly properties.

Comment: The time of System.Configuration has ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `XAML` you could declare all UI stuff(`Color`s, `Style`s etc.) in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="Sample.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Black">#000000</Color>

            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="FontFamilyMedium">
                <OnPlatform.iOS>Roboto-Medium</OnPlatform.iOS>
                <OnPlatform.Android>sans-serif-medium</OnPlatform.Android>
                <OnPlatform.WinPhone></OnPlatform.WinPhone>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontFamilyMedium}" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And then use them from any page:

`<Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Black}" />`

`<Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />`

Don't forget to add to `App.xaml.cs`:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful

Comment: But this makes your app startup time slower, right?

Comment: @batmaci, yes, you're right. You should keep golden middle between reusable code and performance